# UIPickerView changing value of second UIPickerview

Tags: swift, uipickerview

The below is snips of the code that is used to populate two UIPickers and based on the value selected of the first picker it looks up an interest rate based on some other function. This code works when I have only one picker view using the array lenders to populate it. The problem is not that I added a second pickerView with the same information its searching for the information using the wrong pickerView. It should be searching using the pickerView called orginalLender. And not newMortgageLender. Note that the pickerView. I need to use orginalLender. Hope this makes some sense.

```
var currentLender = [Rate]()
var lenders = [String]()
var lendersKey = [String]()
var newLenders = [String]()

 currentLenderPicker.delegate = self
 currentLenderPicker.dataSource = self
 currentLenderPicker.tag = 1

 newLenderPicker.delegate = self
 newLenderPicker.dataSource = self
 newLenderPicker.tag = 2

 orginalLender.inputView = currentLenderPicker
 newMortgageLender.inputView = newLenderPicker
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if pickerView == currentLenderPicker
    {
    return lenders[row]
    }
    else if pickerView == newLenderPicker
    {
        return newLenders[row]
    }

    return ""
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent 
component: Int) -> Int {



    if pickerView == currentLenderPicker
    {
        return lenders.count

    }
    else if pickerView == newLenderPicker
    {
        return newLenders.count
    }

    return 1
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {


    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if pickerView == currentLenderPicker
    {
        orginalLender.text = lenders[row]
    }
    else if pickerView == newLenderPicker
    {
        newMortgageLender.text = newLenders[row]
    }

    // controls the search for the selected lenders rate
    selectedLenderKey = lendersKey[row]

    if let selectedLender = currentLender.filter({ $0.fiName == 
    lenders[row] }).first
    {
        Global.selectedRate = selectedLender
    }


    self.view.endEditing(false)
}

 // these values are set inside a function

  self.currentLender.append(rate)                      
  self.lenders.append(fiName)
  self.lendersKey.append(lenderKey)
  self.newLenders.append(fiName)
                        }
```

The Value is being changed here

```
     if let selectedLender = currentLender.filter({ $0.fiName == lenders[row] }).first
    {
        Global.selectedRate = selectedLender
    }
```

What's happening is that it searches for the rate based on the last picker view selected. I want it to search only using the text field labeled "original lender.

Comment: can you please tell at what stage value is being changed at my end I tried your method with my pickers but hadn't faced any issues I used two pickers . You using one picker tr two

Comment: I added some more comments above and I am still struggling to solve this problem

Comment: selectedLenderKey = lendersKey[row] you are using this array for rate purpose but where are you passing the values of new lenders and lenders array. are you doing like getting row value from picker and passing original value from lendersKey ? still functioning is bit unclear to me.

Comment: The originalLender pickerview returns a lender name that is matched to a rate based on a calculated term value. I think that my problem is that I have two picker views that are populated with the same Array and when the second value is selected it overwrites the first value i want to keep.

Comment: that means you actually do not require the second picker ?

Comment: I want the second picker to have the lenders only and display the new lenders name only. The value will not be used for anything in the view controller

Comment: can you please share the codeFIle ? as I am unable to help you from here. because till I don't know what time value is being changed and what is actual problem I can't do anything

Comment: Yes. But note sure how to share the file?

Comment: GitHub or gitlab account ?

Comment: I am checking please wait

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150247/discussion-between-ios-geek-and-kevin-proctor).